# Testing setInterval

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-runner, setinterval

I have problems with testing code which use setInterval.

My function in component checking if current time is after given time.

What I expect is isAfter flag should be false at start and after 6 seconds should be true (at 2,3,4 seconds should be false)

Now it is still false.

component code

```
  isAfter: boolean;

  private interval;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    const now = new Date();
    const time = now.setSeconds(now.getSeconds() + 5);

    const future = new Date(time);

    this.checkTime(future);
  }

  private checkTime(time: any): void {
    this.interval = setInterval(() => {
      const now = new Date();

      if (now === time) {
        console.log('stop');
        this.isAfter = true;
        clearInterval(this.interval);

      } else {
        console.log('next');
        this.isAfter = false;
      }
    }, 1000);
  }
}
```

spec code

```
import { TestBed, async, ComponentFixture, fakeAsync, tick, discardPeriodicTasks } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

describe('AppComponent', () => {

  let component: AppComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<AppComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [
        AppComponent
      ],
    }).compileComponents();


    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
  }));


  it ('should check time', fakeAsync(() => {

    fixture.detectChanges();
    console.log('isAfter 1', component.isAfter);

    tick(3000);
    fixture.detectChanges();
    console.log('isAfter 3', component.isAfter);

    tick(6000);
    fixture.detectChanges();
    console.log('isAfter 6', component.isAfter);

    discardPeriodicTasks();

  }));

});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if (now === time)
```

This line compares by reference and you have two different date objects here. You should change it to:

```
if (now.getTime() === time.getTime())
```

which compares two primitive numbers instead.

Comment: yeah, tanks ! also I now see that there is a bug in code. Should be now >= time Ehhh

Comment: this test not working in Angular 2

the now date is not updating


`private checkTime(time: any): void {
    this.interval = setInterval(() => {
      const now = new Date();
      console.log(now)
      if (now >= time) {
        console.log('stop');
        this.isAfter = true;
        clearInterval(this.interval);

      } else {
        console.log('next');
        this.isAfter = false;
      }
    }, 1000);
  }`

Comment: I don't think you can compare date objects like this. Again it should be `now.getTime() >= time.getTime()`.

Comment: Btw, for any datetime operations, if you do them in several places in your project, it's worth to add [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) library.

Comment: Yes, I have moment.js, the problem is that the new Date() or moment() in setInterval in Angular 2 is not updating. Maybe is problem with my package.json. I will put it later.